# call notification for Agora using flutter_callkeep

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I've looked everywhere but I haven't found a single useful tutorial on how to use flutter_callkeep with the agora_rtc_engine sdk.

I'd like to know how to send and receive agora calls using the flutter_callkeep package.

Can you please help ?

Comment: You can use the agora_rtm_sdk to first send the call invitation and then once the user receives it, you can use that to trigger the call screen or the call notification. You can read more about it over here: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/rtm_invite_android?platform=Android

Comment: Have you found a solution to your question?  I'm am facing the same.

Comment: I ended up writing my own package. Nothing off the shelf worked for me.

Comment: Meherdeep is right, https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtm seems to be a good package. It came out after I posted my message above.